# postgres error that sequence doesn't exist but nextval returns value for sequence

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to alter a table and need to drop primary key column and then recreate it. This is slightly more complicated because I need to insert a column that is 4th from last, the last 3 columns need to stay last.

I ma executing the following script:

```
DO$$
BEGIN

ALTER TABLE logging.audit_study
    DROP CONSTRAINT audit_study_pkey,
    DROP COLUMN indication,
    ADD COLUMN indication INT,
    ADD COLUMN audit_study_id_tmp INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD COLUMN aud_action_tmp VARCHAR,
    ADD COLUMN transaction_id_tmp BIGINT DEFAULT (TXID_CURRENT());

UPDATE logging.audit_study SET audit_study_id_tmp = audit_study_id;
UPDATE logging.audit_study SET aud_action_tmp = aud_action;
UPDATE logging.audit_study SET transaction_id_tmp = transaction_id;

ALTER TABLE logging.audit_study
    DROP COLUMN audit_study_id,
    DROP COLUMN aud_action,
    DROP COLUMN transaction_id;


ALTER TABLE logging.audit_study RENAME audit_study_id_tmp TO audit_study_id;
ALTER TABLE logging.audit_study RENAME aud_action_tmp TO aud_action;
ALTER TABLE logging.audit_study RENAME transaction_id_tmp TO transaction_id;

PERFORM SETVAL('logging.audit_study_audit_study_id_tmp_seq', (SELECT MAX(audit_study_id)+1 FROM logging.audit_study), true);

END $$
```

I get the following error:

```
[42P01] ERROR: relation "logging.audit_study_audit_study_id_tmp_seq" does not exist Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 26 at PERFORM
```

However, if i execute

```
SELECT nextval('logging.audit_study_audit_study_id_tmp_seq')
```

I get an integer back for the next sequence. The sequence is also listed in the table properties.

I can't seem to understand why during this script, the sequence seems to disappear.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: why the `DO` block? That seems completely unnecessary for what you are doing

Comment: Does `setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('logging.audit_study','audit_study_id'), ...)` work?

Comment: "* I need to insert a column that is 4th from last*" makes no sense. The order of columns in a table is irrelevant

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought `DO` block wraps all statements in a transaction. So if any statement fails, all operations are rolledback. I wanted all of these statements to be rolledback if anything failed. Is the DO block not needed for this use case?

Comment: You don't need a DO block to wrap it into a transaction, just use `begin transaction .... commit;`

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a primary key column declared as SERIAL data type (that creates automatically the related sequence) also drops the related sequence.

Comment: But `ADD COLUMN audit_study_id_tmp INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` adds a sequence